# How can I change the subject line with multiple input boxes in a template in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm new to makros. I use email template rather often and I currently have a static subject line in which I have to change multiple place holders, lets say "Number Place Date".

Is there a way I can open the template and an input box opens, asking for the number, then a second one opens asking for place, and so on?

If also possible, the email should directly be sent after I "okayed" the last input box.

I have been searching for the last two hours to find a how to and have found no answer to my specific problem.

I tried this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        If Item.Subject = "DeineVorlagenName" Then
            Dim customSubjectPart1 As String
            Dim customSubjectPart2 As String
            Dim customSubjectPart3 As String
            
            customSubjectPart1 = InputBox("Gib den ersten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
            If customSubjectPart1 <> "" Then
                customSubjectPart2 = InputBox("Gib den zweiten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
                If customSubjectPart2 <> "" Then
                    customSubjectPart3 = InputBox("Gib den dritten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
                    If customSubjectPart3 <> "" Then
                        Dim combinedSubject As String
                        combinedSubject = customSubjectPart1 & " - " & customSubjectPart2 & " - " & customSubjectPart3
                        
                        Item.Subject = combinedSubject
                        Item.Send ' Automatisches Senden der E-Mail nach Bestätigung der letzten InputBox
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) yet? And [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)?

Comment: Added a First try. But did not work

Answer (score 0):

With `CreateItemFromTemplate` you know the mailitem is correct.

There is no need for a subject in the template to ensure it is the one you want.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub createDVNfromTemplate()
    
    Dim DVN As MailItem
    
    'On Error Resume Next    ' Disable debugging. Enable confusion.
    
    ' change C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ as appropriate
    Set DVN = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\DeineVorlagenName.oft")
    
    Dim customSubjectPart1 As String
    Dim customSubjectPart2 As String
    Dim customSubjectPart3 As String
    Dim combinedSubject As String
    
    'If DVN.Subject = "DeineVorlagenName" Then  ' Unnecessary with CreateItemFromTemplate
    
        customSubjectPart1 = InputBox("Gib den ersten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
            
        If customSubjectPart1 <> "" Then
            customSubjectPart2 = InputBox("Gib den zweiten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
                
            If customSubjectPart2 <> "" Then
                customSubjectPart3 = InputBox("Gib den dritten Teil des Betreffs ein:")
                    
                If customSubjectPart3 <> "" Then
                    combinedSubject = customSubjectPart1 & " - " & customSubjectPart2 & " - " & customSubjectPart3
                    
                    DVN.Subject = combinedSubject
                    
                    DVN.Display
                    ' DVN.Send ' Automatisches Senden der E-Mail nach Bestätigung der letzten InputBox
                        
                End If
            End If
                
        End If
        
    'End If
    
End Sub
```